# What is the difference between the `heroku` and `heroku login` commands?

Tags: heroku, command-line, heroku-cli

the `heroku` and `heroku login` commands both seem to do the exact same thing **when you first download the Heroku cli**. After logging in the commands do not do the same thing.
What is the difference between these two commands? Is there a difference at all?

Comment: Unless you do heroku login, each time you invoke a command it will ask for credentials, but once you use heroku login and verify the credentials, that login is valid till closing the terminal, ie, you won't be asked for credentials till you close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @VipinMohan said:
Unless you do `heroku login`, each time you invoke a command the cli will ask for credentials. Once you use `heroku login` and verify the credentials, that login is valid till closing the command line is closed